# Crear un servidor Socket en C# y conectar con Javascript

Tags: c#, socket, websocket

Resulta que necesito hacer un servidor para comunicar clientes entre si pero en C#.

Este es el codigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;             
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace socket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint direccion = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);

            byte[] payload;
            try
            {
                payload = new byte[255];
                socket.Bind(direccion); 
                socket.Listen(1); 
                Console.WriteLine("Escuchando...");
                Socket listen = socket.Accept();
                int a = listen.Receive(payload, 0, payload.Length, 0);
                Array.Resize(ref payload, a);
                Console.WriteLine("Cliente dice: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(payload)); 
                Console.WriteLine("Conectado con exito");
                socket.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Ok, hasta alli creo que todo bien, pues para conectarme al servidor me utilizo este codigo Javascript

```
        var Server;
        $(document).ready(function() {

            Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://192.168.1.10:1234');

            Server.bind('open', function() {
                console.log("Cliente conectado");
            });

            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                console.log("Cliente desconectado");
            });

            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
                console.log(payload);
            });
            Server.connect();

            // ACA ES DONDE ME DA EL ERROR
            Server.send( 'message', 'Hola' );
        });
```

Estoy utilizando jQuery y una libreria llamada FancyWebSocket.js

Okey cuando ejecuto el codigo JS para conectarme al socket, esta respuesta me da en el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto me da el cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servidor parece funcionar a la perfeccion, pero ahora, como enviar mensajes al servidor y que este se los envie al resto de los clientes conectados?

Comment: Si quieres échale un vistazo a Signalr (programacion en tiempo real), te puede ser muy útil.

Comment: No conozco ese paquete pero he trabajado con sockets y tu error dice que no puede enviar cuando aún está conectando, debes esperar una respuesta al conectar para no lanzar el send hasta que estés seguro de que la conexión fue exitosa.

Comment: el problema es la asincronia debes enviar el mensaje cuando este conectado ,  `Server.bind('open', function() {
                 Server.send( 'message', 'Hola' );
            });` como se ejecuta asincrono intenta enviar el mensaje y el canal de comunicacion no esta preparado por eso el error de `still in CONECTED state`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código:

1. Abre un socket de servidor y lo pone a escuchar. El programa queda bloqueado hasta que llegue una conexión.
2. Cuando llega la conexión, coge lo primero que llega (las cabeceras HTTP) e imprime el mensaje.
3. Sale del programa, cerrando ambos sockets y dejando de escuchar...

Para cuando el JS envia el mensaje, ya no hay nadie en el servidor escuchando.

Si quieres mantener este modelo (single-thread, una única conexión), una vez establecida la conexión entra en un bucle hasta que se cumpla la condición para salir del programa (por ejemplo, que el WebSocket se cierre).

Adicionalmente, en el servidor estás usando sockets mientras que en el cliente estás usando websockets. Aunque relacionados, no son lo mismo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers